# Unable to use Sinhala font in my Android App

Tags: android, font-face, truetype, android-typeface

I want to use a custom font in my Application which will show Sinhala language.
I have tried all the TTF files, but i am unable to view the font.

The font only looks correct in the Samsung devices, but fail to load in the Micromax, spice mobiles.

[I have used all the below fonts](http://www.kaputa.com/sinhalaunicode/sinhalafonts/)

Please help me sort this.

Attaching screen shot from the device
[image]

Comment: It is depends on your device supported languages.

Comment: but previously i had set font for Gujarati, Marathi languages, it worked even if the device did not supported that language, then what could be the issue for the Sinhala font?